# Why plyr is not playing video to fullscreen in fullscreen mode in any of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, plyr.js

i came a crosss very different problem, in `fullscreen` mode my `plyrjs` is not playing video to `fullscreen`

i tried to reproduce the **problem** with same code in **codepen** but it works in **codepen** why?.

**Question:** why same code produces `fullscreen` in **codepen** but not in my project, in any browser.

here is screen shot (played in `fullscreen` mode in my project):

[image]

**

```js
var videoPlayer = new Plyr('#plyr-video');

var src  = 'https://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4';

     videoPlayer.source = {
         type: 'video',
         title: 'Example title',
         sources: [
          {
               src: src,
               type: 'video/mp4',
               size: 720
           }
         ],
         poster: ''
       };
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.7/plyr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.7/plyr.polyfilled.js"></script>
   <video controls crossorigin playsinline id="plyr-video" controlsList="download" controls style="max-width: 533px;max-height: 300px;">
                    <source src="" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="" type="video/webm">
                    <track kind="captions" label="English captions" src="" srclang="en" default>
                  </video>
```

**Codepen demo:**https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/wRdGGB

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `<link`  and `<script`  import statements are declared early on in your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.7/plyr.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.7/plyr.polyfilled.js"></script >
```

Comment: I think what @grupoMasterPlan is suggesting is to put your `<link />` css imports within your `<head>` tag. Example: `<head> (put here) </head>`